# Convert file to base64 and add v-model binding in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-model

I am building a component which has file input fields and being rendered through function in `VueJs`:

```
export default {
    name: 'nits-file-input',
    props: {
        label: String,
    },
    render (createElement) {
        return createElement('div', { class: 'form-group m-form__group'}, [
            createElement('label', this.label),
            createElement('div'),
            createElement('div', { class: 'custom-file'},[
                createElement('input', {
                    class: 'custom-file-input',
                    attrs: { type: 'file' },
                    domProps: {
                        value: self.value
                    },
                    on: {
                        input: (event) => {
                            var reader = new FileReader()
                            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.value)
                            reader.onload = function () {
                                console.log(reader.result);
                            };
                            this.$emit('input', event.target.value)
                        }
                    }
                }),
                createElement('label', { class: 'custom-file-label'}, 'Choose File')
            ])
        ])
    }
}
```

While having the values in v-model I get the path of file but I need to have a `base64` element. currently in my console I'm getting following error:

> Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

[image: file upload error]

Help me out in execution. Thanks

Comment: i think that the size is big and it's not supported

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim File size is 96 KB. I'm using smallest file to do the testing.

Comment: try a file with size under 4kb

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I tried 22 bytes. It still showing same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should set `reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0])`

instead of

`reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.value)` :

```js
on: {
    input: (event) => {
        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0])
        reader.onload = () => {
            console.log(reader.result);
        };
        this.$emit('input', event.target.files[0])
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm unbale to assign base64 value inside my `$emit` function. I am using `let baseFile = ''
                            reader.onload = function () {
                                baseFile = reader.result
                            }; this.$emit('input', baseFile)` can you help with that?

Comment: i hope that i could, please post a new question where you explain your use case and the issue that you're getting

Comment: here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945241/assigning-converted-base64-values-in-javascript-in-vuejs-function

Answer (score 3):

Change to `reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0])`

Following post could be helpful https://alligator.io/vuejs/file-reader-component/